# Static function as eventhandler in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, event-handling

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708217/capturing-tab-in-silverlight-textbox) code to simulate the tab functionality in my silverlight application.

I would really like to avoid writing the function a lot of times because it has to be used on quite a lot of textboxes throughout the application. I have created a static class

```
public static class TabInsert
{
    private const string Tab = "    ";
    public static void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
            textBox.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.SelectionStart),
                    Tab,
                    textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength, (textBox.Text.Length) - (textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength))
                    );
            e.Handled = true;
            textBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart + Tab.Length;
        }
    } 
}
```

so that I can access it from various places liek this `textBox.KeyDown += TabInsert.textBox_KeyDown;`

Is there a way I can do this in XAML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Behavior (System.Windows.Interactivity namespace) to easily attach to textboxes that in the OnAttached() override subscribes to the event and does the handling as you do and unsubscribes in OnDetaching().

Something like:

```
public class TabInsertBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.KeyDown += textBox_KeyDown;
    }

    private const string Tab = "    ";
    public static void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            int selectionStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
            textBox.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    textBox.Text.Substring(0, textBox.SelectionStart),
                    Tab,
                    textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength, (textBox.Text.Length) - (textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength))
                    );
            e.Handled = true;
            textBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart + Tab.Length;
        }
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the behavior is being detached from its AssociatedObject, but before it has actually occurred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Override this to unhook functionality from the AssociatedObject.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= textBox_KeyDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your xaml you would do <TextBox><i:Interaction.Behaviors><local:TabInsertBehavior/></i:Interaction.Behaviors></TextBox>

Comment: I've absolutely agry with xyzzer - the attached behavior is a good workaround. (see also [How to attach behavior in code behind](http://geekswithblogs.net/SilverBlog/archive/2009/09/22/behaviors-how-to-attach-behavior-in-code-behind-silverlight-3.aspx))

Comment: I agree too but this will just build a pretty nasty XAML and that the least I would like to have because there are a lot of textboxes that neede this functionality...

Comment: You can register an attached dependency property that does the same thing as a behavior. It would actually work better for the exact reason you mentioned. Just define a class like TextBoxExtensions, do something like DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoTabs", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnAutoTabsChanged)); then in OnAutoTabsChanged when it gets set to true - subscribe to your event and when it is set to false - unsubscribe. You will then use it as an attribute like <TextBox ext:TextBoxExtensions.AutoTabs="true"/>

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, [there is no direct way to do this in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221357%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).The event handlers you write in the code behind must be instance methods and cannot be static methods. These methods must be defined by the partial class within the CLR namespace identified by x:Class. You cannot qualify the name of an event handler to instruct a XAML processor to look for an event handler for event wiring in a different class scope.